# c grammar LONG (NTAPI name) (type1,type2...);

Tags: c, grammar

I am reading a ring 0 privilege acquiring [source code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/MinimalisticRingZero.aspx) in windows XP

in that code,

there are 2 lines

which are

```
LONG (NTAPI *NtSystemDebugControl)     (int,void*,DWORD,void*,DWORD,DWORD*);
*(DWORD*)   &NtSystemDebugControl =(DWORD)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("ntdll"),"NtSystemDebugControl");
```

it is first time I see such a grammar

what does both of 2 lines means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line creates a function pointer, the second one initializes the function pointer in a rather horrible way (It will fail on 64-bit machines, though that is probably insignificant in this case).

If you're asking what `GetProcAddress` does I suggest reading about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`ULONG_PTR`, it's here for a reason. In the case of `DWORD`'s being compatible with x64 and x86, it is crucial for success. Use it :) The alternative for x64 is `DWORD64` typecasting, instead. GetProcAddress returns the offset for `NtSystemDebugControl` inside `ntdll`

The address associated with `ntdll.dll!NtSystemDebugControl` when viewed on the stack is now pointed to the function pointer which is defined in the typedef.

From here on you can initiate the pointer as such:

```
NtSystemDebugControl My_NtSystemDebugControl;
if (My_NtSystemDebugControl != NULL) {
    My_NtSystemDebugControl(...);
}
```

Basically what this did is resolve the api at runtime without needing to link it at compile time. If your application is viewed in [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/files/ExplorerSuite.exe) then the `IAT (Import-Address-Table)` will only contain `GetProcAddress`, and `LoadLibrary`. But `NtSystemDebugControl` won't be present as it is being resolved at runtime.

The advantages to this is, it hinders heuristic analysis in a lot of anti-viruses, it makes your binary size smaller since you aren't linking a ton of useless libraries at compile-time, and it gives you much more flexibility by only defining functions that you need, and not the entire library!

Also, you should attempt to use `GetModuleHandle("ntdll")`, and comparing the result to `!= NULL` before going into `LoadLibrary("ntdll")` as it's much less intrusive!